# Location of "Choose Store View" add default "All Store Views" selection

Tags: adminhtml, store-view

I want to add "All Store Views" selection in every case under drop down selection.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the template under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/switcher.phtml`

If you want to change some code you can rewrite it's block class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Switcher`

Comment: I want to display default option in every case "All Store Views", in admin or in subadmin also, how it possible?

Comment: @Mathew sorry, it's not too clear. Please update your question with some screenshots etc to clarify

Comment: Check latest updates, in drop down if i have only one website and multiple stores then i want "All Store View" selection option also.